# Почему Pytest выдаёт ошибку из-за фикстур с разным scope?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Моя идея была в том, чтобы при запуске сессии или к примеру модуля, логиниться, получать куки и затем добавлять куки при каждом запуске браузера (для каждого теста).

Я сделал фикстуру которая логинится и скачивает куки, поставил scope=“session”

Но при запуске теста получаю ошибку, из которой единственное что я понимаю это то, что есть какой-то конфликт между фикстурой браузера со scope=“function” и фикстурой которую я сделал, обе находятся в conftest.py Подскажите пожалуйста в чём заключается причина проблемы(по возможности простым языком т.к. я новичок в автоматизации) и как это решать? Если поставить одинаковый скоуп у фикстур, то всё работает, но это не подходит под мою задачу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть две фикстуры, и вы хотите использовать одну в качестве аргумента для другой:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fix1(fix2):
    any_action()
```

Вы должны обязательно соблюсти условие: `scope(fix2) >= scope(fix1)`

**Почему есть такое ограничение:**

Потому что в тот момент, когда вызывается фикстура(fix1), принимающая на вход другую фикстуру (fix1), другая фикстура должна быть доступна.

Код фикстуры со `scope='session'` выполнится один раз за сессию, а код фикстуры со `scope='function'` будет выполняться для каждой тестовой функции по новой.

Более того, фикстура со `scope='session'` будет выполняться в первую очередь, поэтому в момент её выполнения фикстуры со `scope='function'` ещё не существует.

**В вашем случае, фикстура со `scope='session'` пытается получить доступ к фикстуре со `scope='function'`, которой в этот момент еще не существует.**